# how to hide tab outline of tabControl element in WinForms

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

So there is an [ugly outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLaO9.png) of a selected tab's header text. How do I remove/hide it?

Comment: Custom Control with `protected override bool ShowFocusCues => false;`

Comment: Is it possible to change the parameter in tabControl properties window?

Comment: No, `ShowFocusCues` is `protected internal` (belongs to the `Control` class). It's also not browsable.